# Confusion in proof of theorem ($2.7$) in Rudin's Real and complex analysis

Tags: general-topology, compactness

I am not able to fill the gap in proof of following theorem which is stated as...

Let $U$ be an open set in a locally compact hausdorff space $X$, $K\subset U$ and K is compact. Then there exists an open set $V$ with compact closure such that : 
$$K\subset V\subset \overline{V}\subset U$$

Proof : Let $p\in K$ as $X$ is locally compact there exists an open set $V_p$ such that $\overline{V_p}$ is closure. See that this collection $\{\overline{V_p}\}_{p\in K}$ is an open cover for $K$. as $K$ is compact this cover has a finite collection which covers $K$.
Suppose $V_1,V_2,\cdots,V_n$ covers $K$. I now set $V=\bigcup_{i=1}^n V_i$ see that $V$ is open being finite union of open sets and $K\subset V$

Now $\overline{A\cup B}=\overline{A}\cup \overline{B}$ so, for similar reasons we have  $\overline{V}=\overline{\bigcup_{i=1}^n V_i}=\bigcup_{i=1}^n \overline{V_i}$ and see that $\overline{V}$ is compact being finite union of compact sets.

So, I have an open set $V$ of $X$ with compact closure such that $K\subset V\subset \overline{V}$

Suppose my $U$ is $X$ then i am done as i need not check if $\overline{V}$ is in $X$

Suppose not then i am not sure if this closure is in $X$

Just to not get confused i now denote the union $\bigcup_{i=1}^n V_i$ as $G$

As $U^c\neq \emptyset$ I denote this $U^c$ as $C$.

I understood that given $p\in C=U^c$ there exists an open set $W_p$ such that $K\subset W_p$ and $p\notin \overline{W_p}$

I do not understand why $\bigcap_{p\in C}(C\cap \overline{G}\cap \overline{W_p})$ is empty..

Help me to fill this gap..

Comment: "Suppose not then I am not sure if this closure is in **X**" - didn't you mean **U**?

Comment: @Daniel I do not have time to check this. If you are sure about that then you are free to edit.

Comment: I am sure of nothing :) I just share same confusion as posted...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess i got the solution and i thought it is not a better idea to edit the question..

So, I am writing this..

Suppose  $\bigcap_{p\in C}(C\cap \overline{G}\cap \overline{W_p})$ is non empty...

Then i have $x\in \bigcap_{p\in C}(C\cap \overline{G}\cap \overline{W_p})$

In particular, $x\in C\cap \overline{G}\cap \overline{W_x}$

But then We have the condition that if $x\in C$ then $x\notin \overline{W_p}$

Thus we have a contradiction... so,$\bigcap_{p\in C}(C\cap \overline{G}\cap \overline{W_p})$ is empty.

Answer (score 0):

For each $p \in C$ you have that $p \notin C \cap \bar{W_p}$  so in each term you have $p$ missing and if you take the intersection for $p \in  C$ then:

$$\cap_{p \in C}(C \cap \bar{G} \cap \bar{W_p}) \subset C \qquad p \notin (C \cap \bar{W_p}) \implies \cap_{p \in C}(C \cap \bar{G} \cap \bar{W_p}) = \emptyset$$

Also remember that $\bar{G}=\bar{V}$ so you can get the result that you're looking for. I don't know if I explained myself sufficently clear, if I haven't please let me know and I'll try to fix it.

Comment: I am sorry.. I did not understand that first two lines...

Comment: Sorry, I've been out all day. I'll post a larger answer after dinner.

Comment: fine fine... I will be waiting :) Thank you :)

Comment: Please post an answer if you've finished your dinner! It's been $\sim 7$ years!

Answer (score -1):

By local compactness, for each $p \in K$, there exists an open neighborhood $V_p$ of $p$ with $\bar{V_p}$ compact and $\bar{V_p} \subset U$.

By compactness of $K$, there is a finite subset $F$ of $K$ for which $K\subset \bigcup_{p\in F} V_p$. Let $V = \bigcup_{p\in F} V_p$.

Certainly $V$ is open.

Finally, since $F$ is finite, $\bar{V} = \bigcup_{p \in F} \bar{V_p} \subset U$, and $\bar{V}$ is compact.

Comment: you do not know if $\overline{V_p}\subset U$ or not... I have already said that in the question..

Comment: To the contrary, you *do* "know" that -- it's a standard result of topology -- provided the space is a Hausdorff (which is usually part of the definition of "locally compact"): Given a point $p \in U$, then $U$ is a neighborhood of $p$. By definition of local compactness, there is a compact neighborhood $W$ of $p$ with $W \subset U$. Since $W$ is a neighborhood of $p$, there exists an open set $V_p$ with $p \in V_p \subset W$. Then $\bar{V_p} \subset \bar{W}$. Now $W$, being compact, is closed, so that $\bar{W} = W$. Thus $\bar{V_p} \subset W \subset U$, and so $\bar{V_p} \subset U$.

Comment: I do not know then, I only know there exists some neighborhood whose closure is compact... I am not able to convince myself that this is true..

Comment: The usual definition in topology of "locally P" is: each point has a local base of neighborhoods having property P. Nonetheless, in a Hausdorff space, the existence of *some* compact neighborhood implies locally compact in the preceding sense.