# Proof of Theroem 2-7 in Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I am working on the proof of Theorem 2-7 in Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis and I need some help clarifying why p does not belong to the closure of Wp.

Here is a link to the entire theorem.

[Confusion in proof of theorem ($2.7$) in Rudin's Real and complex analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/886066/confusion-in-proof-of-theorem-2-7-in-rudins-real-and-complex-analysis/1048631#1048631)

Comment: because for theorem 2.5, there is also an open set $U$ which contains $p$, and also $U$ is disjoint to $Wp$, so $Wp\in U^c$. so $p$ cannot in the closure of $Wp$ for $\overbar{Wp}\subset U^c$, if u know $A\subset B$ implies $\overbar{A}\subset\overbar{B}$.